# What are some good learning resources?

Tags: resources

I was wondering if there where any good resources like books or programs for learning how to code. I've been trying to learn by watching tutorials but I end up just fallowing the instructions without really knowing how and why things go together the way they do. So I get lost when trying to make my own projects.

I was wondering what are the recommended resources? preferably with plenty of exercises so I could get a lot of practice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpson 
Try sololearn app 
After getting the certificate
Then re-take  the course from 
W3shools  but always remember to practice and inverting the codes you learn 
R. i. P English